# How can i add behaviour to a instance of a class without changing the base class

Tags: python

I get an instance of class from a third party library in my code

```
i = x.get_instance()
```

My code then calls a method from this instance.

```
i.method_a()
```

which will call a method inside this class where i want to add behaviour.

The only way i found now was to

```
class BetterClass(ThirdPartyClass):
    def getMessage(self):
        message = super(BetterClass, self).getMessage()
        ... add behaviour
        return message    

i.__class__ = BetterClass
i.method_a()
```

But what is the better way to add this kind of behaviour as i can't change the instance i get back.
I do not init it myself

Comment: Why don't you just put your working code in a function and call that function instead of `x.get_instance()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
>>> class Example(object):
...   def foo(self):
...       print "foo"
...
>>> a=Example()
>>> a.foo()
foo
>>>
>>> def new_foo(self):
...    Example.foo(self)
...    print "new"
...
>>> funcType = type(Example.foo)
>>> a.foo = funcType(new_foo, a, Example)
>>> a.foo()
foo
new
```

Here, `type` is the [class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type). `funcType` is then an instancemethod:

```
>>> funcType
<type 'instancemethod'>
>>> help(funcType)
...
class instancemethod(object)
 |  instancemethod(function, instance, class)
 |
 |  Create an instance method object.
```

### ...

Also, (thanks @bruno desthuilliers), you could just do:

```
a.foo = new_foo.__get__(a, type(a))
```

instead of using `funcType`.

Comment: The simple syntax is `a.foo = new_foo.__get__(a, type(a))` - and you example doesn't show how to use the original implementation of `a.foo` in `new_foo`. Also, the part of the doc you quote is totally irrelevant, since you're calling `type` with a single argument...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers indeed… my bad. Mixed with the funcType call… Also, miss the part where it should __add__ behaviour, not replace! Should be ok now.

Comment: while we're at it, you may want to print `type(Example.foo)` - it's not a function ;)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that `x.get_instance()` will return an instance of `ThirdPartyClass`, you can monkeypatch `ThirdPartyClass`:

```
from thirdpartlib.module import ThirdPartyClass

def patch_ThirdPartyClass():
    _get_message = ThirdPartyClass.get_message

    def get_message(self):
        message = _get_message()
        # add behaviour here
        return message
    ThirdPartyClass.get_message = get_message

patch_ThirdPartyClass()
```

You just want to make sure this code will be executed only once per process - if you're not sure you can garantee this, you'd better add some flag:

```
def patch_ThirdPartyClass():
    _get_message = ThirdPartyClass.get_message
    if getattr(_get_message, "patched", False):
        return

    def get_message(self):
        message = _get_message()
        # add behaviour here
        return message
    get_message.patched = True        
    ThirdPartyClass.get_message = get_message

patch_ThirdPartyClass()
```

Also you want to make sure this code is executed *before* any call to `x.get_instance()`, obviously.

If for any reason you cannot use the above solution, you can still monkeypatch the method on a per-instance basis:

```
def patch_instance(instance):
    _get_message = instance.get_message

    def get_message(self):
        message = _get_message()
        # add behaviour here
        return message

    instance.get_message = get_message.__get__(instance, type(instance))
    return instance

i = patch_instance(x.get_instance())
```

Same consideration applies wrt/ making sure you only apply this patch once, so you may want to add a similar flag stuff and test as in the class monkeypatch version.

As a last note: if you have to fallback to the `patch_instance` solution and want to make sure *all* calls to `x.get_instance()` return a patched instance, you may also want to patch `x.get_instance` so it does the call to `patch_instance`.

Comment: monkey-patching is frowned upon in python (much more than in ruby, for example)

Comment: Monkeypatching **for no good reason** (like Ruby guys used to do until they ran into troubles) is seen as a bad practice, yes. Monkeypatching is still considered as the "least worse" practical solution for some use case, and when you do have a lib or framework that does not give you the needed entry point / hook / whatever solution to customize some part of the code, then it **is** the way to go - unless of course you're willing to maintain a fork of the full third-part lib/framework/whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a class Foo which has a bar method:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...    def __init__(self, name):
...        self.name = name    
...    def bar(self):
...        print "bar", self.name
```

If you create an instance of this class called `foo`...

```
>>> foo = Foo('eggs')

>>> foo.bar()
bar eggs
```

...then you want to patch the bar method. First define a function:

```
>>> def bar(self):
...    self.__class__.bar(self)   # you can call the original method
...    print "spam", self.name
```

You can patch the instance without monkey-patching the class:

```
>>> import types

>>> foo.bar = types.MethodType(bar, foo, Foo)

>>> foo.bar()
bar eggs
spam eggs
```

Not sure if this is right (probably not a good idea) but it works.

The original class is intact:

```
>>> otherfoo = Foo('foo')

>>> otherfoo.bar()
bar foo
```